# I have a problem with bidirectional data in using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to be able to understand why the following error happens to me.

I currently have a service which returns an *object*.
This service is used to share information between two controllers, *controller "1"* and *controller "2"*. 
From controller "2", I update driver information "1".

**Error:**
When the information in controller "1" is modified, I also update controller "2"  information (unwanted). 
In my controller "2" I do not use the service to load my information, it should not be modified.
**Demo:**
[image: Demo]

**Example on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/inactivity/y13xt6pz/40/).**

**Steps to reproduce the error:**

1. Press the Edit button in any row. (The information is loaded in the form).
2. Edit the "Price" field (the information in the table is modified) (Unwanted).

Also investigate that to obtain data in a "unidirectional" way you can use `ng-value`.

**Additional questions:**

1. How can I send my data to the service without affecting the information in the table (Controller "2")?
2. Is it correct to implement `ng-value` together with `ng-model`? Could you explain me how?

Thank you!

**Fiddle Code:**
*app.js*

```
angular.module("app", [])
.factory("Service", function(){
    var data={}
  return data;
})
.controller("FormController", function($scope, Service){
    $scope.service = Service;
  $scope.updateData = function(data){
    //TODO: Implement logic to update database
  }

})
.controller("DataController", function($scope, Service){
  $scope.service = Service;
  // Fake database
  $scope.dataPrices = [
    {
        code: 'AA',
        price: 111
    },
    {
        code: 'BB',
        price: 222
    },
    {
        code: 'CC',
        price: 333
    }
  ];
    $scope.editData = function(index){
        $scope.service.data = $scope.dataPrices[index];
    }
});
```

*index.html*

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="FormController" >
<form name="mainForm"  novalidate>
    <div>
        <label>Code</label>
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="code"
                ng-required="true"
                ng-disabled="true"
                ng-model="service.data.code"
            />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Price</label>
        <div>
            <input
                    type="number"
                    name="price"
                    ng-required="true"
                    ng-model="service.data.price"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button
          type="submit" 
          ng-click="updateData(data)">
          Save
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div ng-controller="DataController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="dat in dataPrices">
            <td>{{dat.code}}</td>
            <td>{{dat.price}}</td>

            <td>
                <button ng-click="editData($index)">
                    Edit
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: JS call by reference issue. Use `$scope.service.data = angular.copy($scope.dataPrices[index]);`

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use

```
angular.copy($scope.dataPrices[index])
```

to avoid updating data in the table. It will create a deep copy of your object.

And for sending data to service, you will need to create getter setter method in service.

Here is the working example https://jsfiddle.net/q7L4ebaz/1/